# GPS detecting stationary?

Tags: gps, tinygps, speed

can someone please point me at some code snippets to detect when the GPS is stationary. I am currently using tinyGPS library and it is working fine, but my data-logger has thousands of stationary details I'd like to not bother logging. Currently I am using this,

```
uint8_t speedZero() {
uint8_t spd = gps.speed.mph();
  if (spd < 5) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return spd;
  }
}
```

But it is too granular at slow speeds, but the NEO-6M drifts a lot and 5mph standing still is not uncommon.

I have tried comparing Last Lat/Lon but not having any success as this Math is waaaay out of my skill-zone.

Comment: Just add accelerometer sensor to your device. It's just around 1USD and it will easily detect lack of movement.

Comment: `I have tried comparing Last Lat/Lon but not having any success as this Math is waaaay out of my skill-zone.` - find a function that gives you a distance between two lat/long points, the remaining *math* is trivial

Comment: I gave an answer in PHP a few month ago, maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222382/get-lat-long-given-current-point-distance-and-bearing/26938066#26938066

Comment: Only log the values when they've significantly changed?

Answer (score 1):

I found this to get me started.

http://apexlogic.net/code-bank/arduino/serial-gps-find-distance-between-two-points/